# How do objects slide under one another?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

I am making a small Robot to pick up things off the ground, and I am trying to understand the physics behind objects sliding under one another. The exact scenario that I am talking about in real life can be represented by how a simple pie server slide under a slice of cake or pie in order to pick them up. What is the physics of this and how does the geometry of the objects involve affect the physics? (For instance, I would assume the thicker the pie server's flat bottom is, the lower the chance that it will slide under something?)

The way I currently rationalise this situation is that when something like a pie-server try to slide under a slice of pie, it must provide a force that should be overcome the weight of that slice of pie, and the way it provides that force is by accelerating towards the pie and exerting a contact force normal to the walls of the pie which produces a frictional force on the pie. This frictional force provides the lift for the slice of pie which allows the slice of pie to be lifted slightly such that the pie-server is now under the slice of pie.

Below is my working for the application of my hypothesis but for my robot. I presume this is an extremely simplistic, if not, the downright wrong way to think of this scenario. Please tell me what is the actual physics behind this scenario is and how I may adapt my working in order to incorporate the true mechanism behind this phenomenon.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTnpk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Seems right to me

You can account for friction - it can be especially large for wet objects, like a pie.

Thick pie server changes the situation completely - it starts to deform the pie, rip it, and then force depends on how easy it is to break the pie.

If pie server is thin, and it is not too rubbery, idea seems ok. Need to overcome gravity, pie mass, in a form of a force of a sliding pie-server

I think your bigger problem will be to avoid destroying an object - if grabber instead pinches the object, rather than slides under it. Solution could be to tilt an object first, or slide it off a shelf.